# PHP's SMTP configuration on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, smtp, php.ini

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp

Looking at the manual, it specifies that the php.ini option for selecting an SMTP server is a windows-only thing. What do I do to configure it to use a specific domain/IP/port for a linux box, or otherwise?

Am I out of choices and need to use something that isn't native to PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Linux system php expects to call `sendmail` (using the `sendmail_path` setting to locate the binary).  You can use a lightweight send-only mta like [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) if you simply want to send all your mail to another destination.  msmtp is available in Ubuntu, and the configuration is very simple.